# Multiple Push Segues to One View Controller in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have an application in Xcode 4.6 that uses storyboards. The root view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, and all view controllers in the application are accessed via push segues via the navigation controller.

I ran into a complication when I wanted to have one particular view controller (called photos) accessed via a push segue by two different view controllers. I ended up with what appeared to be a navigation controller inside a navigation controller in the photos controller after I added the second segue. The goal is to just have (in photos) one navigation bar with a dismiss button that (when pressed) pops back to whichever of the two view controllers presented the photos view controller. I am somewhat new to iOS and I am not sure of the best way to accomplish this or how to generally handle this situation.

Here is a picture of my storyboard for reference:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you set up the segues? I don't see this problem if I have two buttons in the root view controller of the navigation controller, one that segues to the next controller in line, and one that segues to the one after that (and the next one in line also segues to that last one). Everything works fine, there's just one navigation bar, and the back button has the title of the controller that pushed it.

Comment: I added a picture of my storyboard to clarify my issue.

Comment: It's a little too blurry to read the names. Is the one with the 2 blue rectangles in it a tab bar controller? If so, are you pushing from the tab bar controller, or is that problematic controller one of its view controllers? Is only the first controller on the left a navigation controller?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the one with the two blue rectangles is a regular view controller with a tab bar in it (it is set as the tab bar controller delegate).  I created a segue from one of the tab bar buttons to the "problematic" view controller. All of these controllers are part of the same navigation stack/embedded in the same navigation controller, originating with the root controller which is the first one on the far left. When I added the second segue from the view controller with the tab bar to the problematic controller, that is when I got the double navigation bar issue.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't duplicate your double navigation bar. Did you actually make the segue directly from a tab bar button to the problematic controller, or from the controller -- I wasn't able to make a connection directly from the button, Xcode wouldn't allow it. If you haven't already, you might try deleting that segue, and remaking it to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should really do it programmatically using SotyboardID. It's only a few lines of code in each ViewControler.